# How to access nested directory in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

So I have a basic directory with this structure.

```
movies = {
    'Mary': {
        'Big':
        {
        'Watched': 1,
        'Rating': 'G'
        }
    },
    'Frank': {
        'Cinderella':
        {
        'Watched': 1,
        'Rating': 'G'
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to iterate through all the movies for a given username. As well as add more when I need them. That is I will say have 'Mary'. How do I list all the movies, with the rating and watched under that movie, for each movie?
How would I add a new movie?

I'm kinda new to this in python and searched the previous questions, but those dictionaries were a lot more complicated than this one, which is why I'm asking.

Edit:

```
def displaymembers():
    for key in movies:
        print("%s" % key)
```

So far this is how I display the people, but not sure how to access all the movies inside the key?

Comment: @RobGwynn-Jones Something very basic only :/

Comment: Edited post for you

Comment: Try: `print("%s" % movies[key])`

Comment: Do you just want to print the movie names? You can do a nested for loop then.

Comment: I need to access the names, and their respective information, as well as how to add a new movie for a user, or add a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest for loops to continue to iterate through the inner dicts. You can use `dict.items` to get both the key and its value.

```
for name, movie_dict in movies.items():
    print(name)
    for movie_name, movie_stats in movie_dict.items():
        print("{:<5}{}".format('', movie_name))
        for key, value in movie_stats.items():
            print("{:<10}{}, {}".format('', key, value))
```

Otherwise you can do it this way with just the key and chain it along to get the values for each key. `dict[key1][key2][keyn]`

```
for name in movies:
    print(name)
    for movie_name in movies[name]:
        print("{:<5}{}".format('', movie_name))
        for key in movies[name][movie_name]:
            print("{:<10}{}, {}".format('', key, movies[name][movie_name][key]))

# Output
Mary
     Big
          Watched, 1
          Rating, G
Frank
     Cinderella
          Watched, 1
          Rating, G
```

The problem with this approach is that you must have the same structure throughout your `movies` dict, if there is a case where some key might not have a value of a dictionary, say `Mary` has a list or somethings instead of a dictionary as the value, then you will need to handle that case. If your dictionary will always follow the structure you've shown then you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: How would I add a new movie for a given person? Along with it's watched value and the rating value?

Comment: As shown in the second example, you can chain it along so `movies['Mary']['New Movie'] = { 'Watched': 1, 'Rating': 'G'}`

Comment: Yup! I figured it out. Thank you so much! :)